# How to access function in another JS file

Tags: gwt

I added another JS file to my project : `test.js`

and I have the code in `test.js`:

```
var testObj = {
  hello : function(){
    alert("hello world");
  }
}
```

and I added this line to the main HTML file in my project:

the script is under the same folder as HTML file.

In the Java code, I call this function by:

```
public static native void helloWorld()/*-{
    testObj.hello();
}-*/;
```

But when I run it, it tells me `testObj is undefined`. But in the browser console, when I do: `testObj.hello()` and it is working (so the JS file is loaded).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself.

change the call to:

```
public static native void helloWorld()/*-{
    $wnd.testObj.hello();
}-*/;
```

`$wnd` must be `$wnd`, `window`, `document`, `this` or `$doc` will not work.